# proper way to define resources for singular name controller and model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

if I have `articles controller` and `article model` I would create `resources: articles` in `config/routes.rb`

but let's say I have a singular controller that I want to use for control panel such as `control_panel_controller.rb` (not control_panel**s**_controller.rb) and a model that matches that controller `control_panel.rb` Would I just use `resources: control_panel` as proper ruby convention or I would have to do it some other way?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify singular routes and override the default controller name that is expected.

Here is how I set up my home page:

```
resource :home, only: [:show], controller: 'home'

class HomeController < ApplicationController
...
end
```

This gives a helper called 'home_path' that generates the '/home' URL.

Take a look at the Rails routing guide; it does cover these options they're just not super obvious.

Edit: btw, your model names are totally independent of the controllers/routes. Of course it's good convention to make them match where possible, but often times as your app grows there will be many models or service objects that don't directly correspond to a controller with CRUD actions for it.

Comment: So if I have a picture.rb model and want to link it to control_panel_controller.rb in routes I would just have to do resources: pictures, controller: 'control_panel'     ?

Comment: Like I said, models are completely independent from the routes and controllers. The routes file does not "link" them. If you say 'resources :things' that will produce url helpers like things_path, thing_path(obj), edit_thing_path(obj), etc; and route them to ThingsController. But inside ThingsController you can choose to query whatever models you wish.

Comment: Oh ok. in my case it would be resources: control_panel

Comment: I think even for singular resources-- defined by 'resource' without the trailing 's'-- Rails convention is to expect the controller to still have a plural name. That's why you can use the :controller option in the resource definition to override the controller name. In my example, if i had left out that option it would have looked for HomesController (note the 's').